# conditional link query mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I need help to make the code below viable

```
 public ActionResult _StaffBlogs()
    { 
        string userkey = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
        if (userkey != null || userkey != " ")
        {
            var blogstaff = db.Blogs
                .Where(u => u.IsLive == true)
                .Where(u => u.UserGuId == userkey)
                .OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
                .Take(10);
            return PartialView(blogstaff);
        }
       return View();
    }
```

In the view I have this condition

```
  @if(Request.IsAuthenticated )
    {
   @{Html.RenderAction("_StaffBlogs", "Blog");}
     }
```

The  Error shown
compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: 1) What are you trying to do? 2) What problem are you having?

Comment: I want the main query to execute if the a person has been authenticated.  I have put isautheticated condition in the view but it still giving exception

Comment: What exception are you getting? Can you please post that part of your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was and extra @ before the renderpartial removing it took away the error